# How to use filebeat to find password in log

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, filebeat

I have an Elasticsearch 7.1 and i have configure filebeat to collect all log.
I want to check if i have password in log.

So anyone have an idea how can i find all password in log using filebeat.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to query your data in some Elasticsearch Indices using the REST API of Elasticsearch and/or make use of a frontend like Kibana shipping with it's own set of query languages.

What Indices your data is stored in and how this looks depends entirely on your setup.

- Filebeat only collects the data.
- Elasticsearch stores the data.
- You'll also have to know what password you're looking for or know the pattern of the log lines in question of a program that writes password to a log
- You did not mention any data shipper (like Logstash)